# Dynamic magnetic field Vs electronics

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

It seems dynamic magnetic field may damages electronics components like diode,  transistor etc, probably via electromagnetic induction.  How much strength and what frequency magnetic field is dangerous? Surprisingly there is hardly any info on Google on this.

Comment: I think the reason you're having trouble googling it is that you're asking the question very vaguely. I would recommend doing some rough scaling calculations using Maxwell's equations to see how magnetic fields may induce a damaging current.

Comment: Can you provide citations concerning damage possibilities?